# HTML email signature sent from outlook to gmail adds extra space

Tags: html, email, html-email, signature

My html code for outlook is adding extra space between each row when I send to Gmail iOS.

How do I work around this? I tried inline CSS with each paragraph tag and it still seems to ignore it.
Anything helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Can you post your signature code??